# Compare two consecutive lines and update the first line with next line in teradata

Tags: teradata

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

I need to compare the consecutive rows of the below given table , and update the first row field with the second row field.

```
MBR     JOIN DT     FIELD1  FIELD2  FIELD3  OPEN_DT     CLOS_DT      LLKEY      UPD_LLKEY
12345   2014-07-30  D       UNK     S       2014-07-31  **2014-08-24**  715700024   **721200013**
12345   2014-09-11  D       UNK     UNK     **2014-09-13**  2014-10-01  **718600061**   735800004
12345   2014-09-29  D       UNK     UNK     2014-10-01  8888-12-31  735800004   735800004
```

here ineed to compare the two consecutive lines (first_line.CLOS_DT and second_line.OPEN_DT) , if its not matching need to update first_line.CLOS_DT with the second_line..OPEN_DT , UPD_LLKEY with LLKEY of second line . And the desired output is

```
MBR     JOIN DT     FIELD1  FIELD2  FIELD3  OPEN_DT     CLOS_DT     LLKEY       UPD_LLKEY
12345   2014-07-30  D       UNK     S       2014-07-31  **2014-09-13**  715700024   **718600061**
12345   2014-09-11  D       UNK     UNK     **2014-09-13**  2014-10-01  **718600061**   735800004
12345   2014-09-29  D       UNK     UNK     2014-10-01  8888-12-31  735800004   735800004
```

Any help would be highly appreciated .. :)

Thanks,
Apmsa

Answer (score 0):

save this to new table Tempo

```
SELECT  mb_r
,join_dt
,open_dt
,close_dt

,COALESCE(MAX(open_dt) OVER (PARTITION BY mb_r  ORDER BY open_dt ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING), close_dt) A2

FROM TEMP2
```

now update temp2 table from tempo table

```
UPDATE temp2 C1
  FROM (SELECT  mb_r
    ,join_dt
    ,open_dt
    ,close_dt
    ,A2 from tempo) D1
   SET close_dt = d1.A2
 WHERE C1.mb_r = d2.mb_r
and c1.join_dt=d2.join_dt;
```

you can also include the other coulmn you need to update in similar way to the above queries.